# Vmware 1.x on ubuntu 10.04 server amd64 alpha 3?

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-server

I would like to install vmware server 1.x on ubuntu 10.04 server amd64.

Would this work? Or should I go with ubuntu 9.04 for now?

*Edit:* In the meantime I decided to go with vmware 2.x. I just installed it on ubuntu server 8.04 LTS amd64 and I am quite happy with it so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have also been looking at this... been using VMWare Server since 1.0.4... using 1.0.10 at the moment but want to update to Ubuntu 10.04 AMD64... From what I have read 1.x is unlikely to work on 10.04... Followed instructions at top of page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Server for Ubuntu 9.10 (VMWare Server 2.0.x) which does install VMware 2.0.2 ok using the script, however firefox 3.6 as with 10.04 will not load the console... Google Chrome does... however as mentioned VMware 2.x is completely awful in comparison to 1.x WTF is with this obsession of replacing nice efficient binaries with bloody awful browser based crap!!! (rant over) Did manage to set up a VM but then just sat there telling me it was loading but not doing anything... impressive!! At the moment I am checking out VirtualBox, it is in the Ubuntu repositories (virtualbox-ose-qt in synaptic) so installs and updates automatically and sounds like it does 3d GPU virtualization aswell. Running 10.04 from LiveCD so cannot check this yet, will reboot and check virtualbox on UbuntuStudio 8.04 AMD64 on main partition

Comment: The binary client was much better and i really miss it. Having problems with the browser client all the time. Either it needs 5-10 (!) attempts to cpnnect or it connects but the console with the desktop does not connect.

Comment: I wonder if Oracle will really continue VirtualBox as a free and open product.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably you mean VMWare Server 1.x, if so WHY would you go with v1.x when 2.0.2 is out?

Oh and 2.0.2 doesn't support U10 yet by the way.

edit - ok, seeing as we're having comprehension issues here; 'would this work' - NO, 'should I go with ubuntu 9.04 for now' - yes - but even then you'll still need v2.0.2 to be certain - clear?

Comment: "Doesn't support" doesn't necessarily mean "doesn't work". It's natural that they wouldn't officially support an OS that hasn't been released yet, but that doesn't mean they haven't been preparing for it.

Comment: this does not answer my question, i asked for 1.x. i like 1.x

Comment: You don't have to be a cock about it, v1 is end-of-life'd and only ever supported Ubuntu 6 anyway, let alone 9 or 10 - hence why I was trying to help you. v2 is a much better product and support later versions of ubuntu but, as you so clearly make out, you might not 'like' it - your call.

Answer (score 1):

VMware Server 1.0.10 was only released in 2009 so as far as VMware seem to be concerned, it is a current and supported product.

I have seen solutions that require kernel recompilation with an option enabled that the standard Ubuntu kernel does not use.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I have to say like the rest of the people here, I disagree with "chopper".
Don't know if the underlying visualization is perhaps better / more efficient, but the management for V2 is unusable crap.